# Length of the string is providing wrong information

Tags: powershell

I want to detect if the machine has only one partition or many - but I want to look only on physical drives.

I list the drives and then remove some garbage from solution:

```
# get all partitions from physical drives in the machine
$temp_string = [System.IO.DriveInfo]::getdrives() | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 'Fixed'} | Select-Object -Property RootDirectory

# remove garbage strings like
# "RootDirectory"
# "-------------"
$drives = $temp_string -replace("RootDirectory","") -replace("-------------","") -replace("@{=","") -replace("}","")


# print out how many drives we have:
$drives
C:\
D:\
G:\
# print how many characters have a result
$drives.Length
3
```

I expect the output to be the number of characters for all partitions, not only one line.
It is always showing only 3 chars, even if you have more partition than 1.

Comment: Since `$drives` is an array, the `Length` property gives the number of items in the collection, not the length of the items themselves. So, as you have 3 items, your output will always be 3.  Here's a simple example, to demonstrate: `$test = "aaa","bbbbbbb","c","dddddddd";  $test.Length`

Comment: Use `$temp_string.GetType()` to get the type of the object. The replaces do nothing...

Comment: Correct @boxdog. But why if I have one drive, it gives me also three items in the collection?

Comment: @GustawSolski Are you sure it's an array at that point?  Likely you get back a single object in the variable if there is only one drive, rather than an array with 1 item in it.  You can check the type of the object like this: `Get-Member -InputObject $drives`.  For an array, I'd expect the type to show as `System.Object[]` and for a single item, as `System.String`.  If it is a single string you have, then you will get back the character count of that string.

Comment: @boxdog another interesting thing...
When I am using this script on Windows 7 Enterprise and Windows Server 2012 I got different results...

Comment: $temp_string = [System.IO.DriveInfo]::getdrives() | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 'Fixed'} | Select-Object -Property RootDirectory
$drives
echo 'in 0 element of array is ' $drives[0] 
echo 'in 1 element of array is ' $drives[1] 
echo 'in 2 element of array is ' $drives[2] 
echo 'Length of array' $drives.Length
echo 'Count of array' $drives.Count

Comment: On Windows Server 2012 R2 I am receiving an output:
C:\
D:\
G:\
in 0 element of array is 
C:\
in 1 element of array is 
D:\
in 2 element of array is 
G:\
Length of array
3
Count of array
3

Comment: But on Windows 7 Enterprise with one drive:
C:\
in 0 element of array is 
C
in 1 element of array is 
:
in 2 element of array is 
\
Length of array
3
Count of array

Comment: So in the array $disk[0] I have a whole string "C:\" but in the same script in another computer in array $disk[0] is "C"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using WMI objects:

```
@(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3}).Count
```

From WMI:

```
0 = Unknown
1 = No Root Directory
2 = Removable Disk
3 = Local Disk
4 = Network Drive
5 = Compact Disc
6 = RAM Disk
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is `Count` rather than `length`. Also, PowerShell always returns objects. This is easy to work with.

[image]

I can go into more details like:

[image]

[image]

So this is what you really need.

```
$temp_string.RootDirectory.name.count
```